# Mpdf - page selectors or css to specific page in automatically added pages

Tags: css, pdf, mpdf

I can't have a page selectors in mpdf because page are added automatically because of text length. Can I use css to a specific page? For example something like @page:nth-childs(3)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No. `::nth-child` pseudoselector is only supported for table elements.

https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html

There is currently no way to alter CSS for a specific page number in mPDF.